# Why when I export shapefile to CSV in R the file result does not maintain the same structure?

Tags: r, export-to-csv, shapefile

I have a shapefile with three columns: gid, which is the ID, rud, the variable I am interested in, and geometry.

I am trying to export that shapefile to csv with the following code:

```
write.csv(grid, "path\\grid_rud.csv")
```

where grid is my shapefile. However, the CSV file has not just three columns, it appears very weird (look picture below). I have tried adding col.names or row.names, but the result is the same.

I think it is because of the geometry column. I have tried to remove the column, and after export it:

```
grid = grid %>% select('gid','rud')
```

However, the column geometry does not disappear. Any idea how can I export my file to a csv? I am just interested in export columns gid and rud.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of geometry column you must first reclass your `grid` sf object to something else, i.e. to a data.frame. For that there's `sf::st_drop_geometry()` , though  `as.data.frame()`, `as_tibble()` and the likes would work too.

Or if you happen to read data from Shapefile but not care about shapes at all, you can import just the attribute table from *dbf* file.

```r
library(dplyr)
# nc example from sf library
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# select 2 columns from sf object, geometry is still there
nc %>% select(NAME, CNTY_ID) %>% head()
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.07282 xmax: -75.77316 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#>          NAME CNTY_ID                       geometry
#> 1        Ashe    1825 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
#> 2   Alleghany    1827 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
#> 3       Surry    1828 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
#> 4   Currituck    1831 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
#> 5 Northampton    1832 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
#> 6    Hertford    1833 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...

# drop geometry, select 2 columns from resulting data.frame
nc_df <- sf::st_drop_geometry(nc)
nc_df %>% select(NAME, CNTY_ID) %>% head()
#>          NAME CNTY_ID
#> 1        Ashe    1825
#> 2   Alleghany    1827
#> 3       Surry    1828
#> 4   Currituck    1831
#> 5 Northampton    1832
#> 6    Hertford    1833

# if you don't care about geometry, you can read just the dbf of Shapefile
nc_dbf <- foreign::read.dbf(system.file("shape/nc.dbf", package="sf"))
nc_dbf %>% select(NAME, CNTY_ID) %>% head()
#>          NAME CNTY_ID
#> 1        Ashe    1825
#> 2   Alleghany    1827
#> 3       Surry    1828
#> 4   Currituck    1831
#> 5 Northampton    1832
#> 6    Hertford    1833
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new in R, and I was completely lost.